# OpenCL-Shared memory access

Tags: c, opencl, gpu

I am using openCL for my application and would like to know how to retain memory on the GPU after the 1st return of the function.
ie.
Send 100b to GPU do some math, return another 100b and also retain the same 100b with the GPU so that I dont need to send it to the CPU then back to the GPU in the next iteration.

Eg.

send a={1,2,3}

kernel__ calc's b=a+1, so b={2,3,4}
next time I call some fn. it must return (3,4,5}, I want to do this without the transferring to CPU then back to GPU

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put the data you want into a CL buffer (cl_mem), this abstraction allows you to manipulate chunks of GPU memory.

Answer (score 0):

take a look this code.

```
     imageI= clCreateImage2D(context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,&format,img.cols,img.rows,0,0,&err); 
 CHECK_CL_ERROR(err);

 err = clEnqueueWriteImage(queue,imageI,CL_TRUE,origin,region,img.cols*sizeof(uchar),0,img.data,0,NULL,NULL);
 CHECK_CL_ERROR(err);

 imageJ= clCreateImage2D(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,&format,img.cols,img.rows,0,0,&err);
CHECK_CL_ERROR(err);

 err = clEnqueueWriteImage(queue,imageJ,CL_TRUE,origin,region,img.cols*sizeof(uchar),0,img.data,0,NULL,NULL);
 CHECK_CL_ERROR(err);

 cl_kernel gauss = clCreateKernel(program, "gauss",&err);
 CHECK_CL_ERROR(err);

 err = clSetKernelArg(gauss, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&imageI);
 CHECK_CL_ERROR(err);
err = clSetKernelArg(gauss, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&imageJ);
CHECK_CL_ERROR(err);
 err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue,gauss,2,NULL,szGlobalWorkSize,szLocalWorkSize,0,NULL,&event);
 CHECK_CL_ERROR(err);
```

And now i transferring the imageJ to the other kernel.

```
Gradient= clCreateImage2D(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,&format,img.cols,img.rows,0,0,&err); 
     CHECK_CL_ERROR(err);

     Angle= clCreateImage2D(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,&format,img.cols,img.rows,0,0,&err);
    CHECK_CL_ERROR(err);

     cl_kernel sobel = clCreateKernel(program, "sobel",&err);
     CHECK_CL_ERROR(err);

     err = clSetKernelArg(sobel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&imageJ);
     CHECK_CL_ERROR(err);
    err = clSetKernelArg(sobel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&Gradient);
    CHECK_CL_ERROR(err);
     err = clSetKernelArg(sobel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&Angle);
    CHECK_CL_ERROR(err);
err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue,sobel,2,NULL,szGlobalWorkSize,szLocalWorkSize,0,NULL,&event);
     CHECK_CL_ERROR(err);
```

and never pass through the CPU.